# Gatsby with nginx - redirect is broken - trailing / (slash)

Tags: nginx, webserver, digital-ocean, http-status-code-301

My gatsby site redirects to trailing slash and then redirects again back to non-trailing slash.

nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
      listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        root /var/www/example.com/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name www.example.com;

        location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:html)$ {
          add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
        }

        location = /sw.js {
          add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
        }

        location /page-data {
          add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
        }

        location /static {
          add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
        }

        location ~* \.(?:js|css)$ {
          add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
        }

    error_page  404  /404.html;
}
```

When I open my website with a trailing slash, I see a redirect to the same URL but without a trailing slash:

```
example.com/hello-world/ -> example.com/hello-world
```

That's the expected behavior.

**But** when I open my website without a trailing slash, I see a redirect to a trailing slash, and then a redirect to without a trailing slash again.

```
example.com/hello-world -> example.com/hello-world/ -> example.com/hello-world
```

This should not happen. Where did I go wrong in my configuration? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything in your config that would make redirecting "expected behaviour".  Are there any other nginx conf files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` or something in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` that might cause the redirects?  Maybe something in your ssl snippets files?  Are you sure it is a server-side `3xx` redirect and not a client-side redirect based on the contents of your `hello-world`?  The trailing slash redirect would normally be due to an nginx `rewrite` somewhere which I don't see in your config.

Comment: Nothing related to redirections in the other files on my VM. I started my website locally and I can't see this behavior. Locally it just redirects from `hello-world/` to `hello-world` as expected.

Comment: "Locally it just redirects from hello-world/ to hello-world as expected."
Why is this expected?  I don't see this in your config.

Comment: I guess that’s what Gatsby.js is doing on my behalf.

Comment: Yeah okay.  I don't see any issue (related to redirects anyway) with your nginx config.  I suspect your issue is on the gatsby.js side then.  Not enough information in your post to help you.

Comment: Thanks @mattpr for pointing me in the right direction. I found this issue https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/27889#discussioncomment-254854 regarding Gatsby. Seems like I have to use trailing slashes everywhere. If you want, you can answer the question with this issue regarding Gatsby + give me a hint how I need to rewrite my nginx config for redirecting to trailing slashes instead of no slashes :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## nginx

Nginx's behaviour regarding slashes is documented [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

> If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash
> character, and requests are processed by one of proxy_pass,
> fastcgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, scgi_pass, memcached_pass, or grpc_pass,
> then the special processing is performed. In response to a request
> with URI equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a
> permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested
> URI with the slash appended. If this is not desired, an exact match of
> the URI and location could be defined like this:
>
> ```
> location /user/ {
>     proxy_pass http://user.example.com; 
> }
>
> location = /user {
>     proxy_pass http://login.example.com; 
> }
> ```

This doesn't apply to you because you are not using CGI or upstream app server...you are just serving files (if I understand correctly).

I'm not a gatsby expert but from the [link](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/27889#discussioncomment-254854) in your comment...

> Gatsby works better, smoother, cleaner (etc.) with trailing slashes

There are a variety of nginx configs floating around from people that have used them successful with Gatsby.  Here is [one](https://raghuvirkasturi.com/gatsby-nginx-conf/) for instance.

The most relevant parts for you are...

redirect paths that don't contain `.` or `?` AND don't end with `/` to the same path but with trailing `/`.

e.g. redirect `/foo/bar` to `/foo/bar/` but don't mess with `/foo/bar.ext` or `/fo.o/bar` or `/foo/bar?hello`.

```
rewrite ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent
```

try to serve the requested URI interpreting it in the following order of preference:

- as is (path to file)
- as a directory
- as directory containing `index.html` file
- finally 404 error if none of the above were valid

```
try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.html =404;
```

## gatsby

From the gatsby [issue link](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/27889#discussioncomment-254854) you posted they say the following:

> Explicitly use the trailing slash in all usages of the `<Link>` component and/or invocations of `navigate()`

and

> Install `gatsby-plugin-force-trailing-slashes`. Even though Gatsby generates the static html pages within their own named directories by default, this plugin forces the path value for each page to end in a / - critical for configuring the core Gatsby @reach/router at build time.

and then finally rebuild the gatsby site since some of this config only has impact at build time.